# Using Xlswrite for cell array

Tags: excel, matlab, import, cells

I understand that the `xlswrite` cannot directly populate the contents of the cell array to the excel sheet. Somehow I'm missing a logic in my code where I need to populate every single element exported to a sheet. say my cell array has cells in it and characters example

```
Names = (1x1 cell) (1x1 cell) (1x1 cell) (1x1 cell)
```

or say

```
Names= {{'Brian'};{'Andy'};{'Katherine'};{'crystal'};{'Thomas'};{'Michael'}; {'Maria'}.........};
```

tried `xlswrite` directly but it didn't work. Understood the point that it can print one at a time (correct me if im wrong).

```
saveto = 'D:\Data\';
xlswrite([saveto,'test'],Names{1},'A1');
```

would work only for one element in cell. Writing a for loop is not helping me as well

```
 for aa=1:length(Names)
     saveto = 'D:\Data\';
     xlswrite([saveto,'test'],Names{aa},'A1:A2000'); % A2000 is used as a random number 
 end
```

your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to "flatten" your `Names` before writing to the xls:

```
Names= {{'Brian'};{'Andy'};{'Katherine'};{'crystal'};{'Thomas'};{'Michael'};{'Maria'}}
NamesToWrite = reshape([Names{:}], size(Names));
```

then use `xlswrite` on `NamesToWrite`:

```
saveto = 'D:\Data\';
xlswrite([saveto,'test.xls'],NamesToWrite);
```

This happens because, if you pass a cell array to the function, its elements need to be either numeric scalars or strings.